# accessing a dictionary from a list of dictionaries using value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries of

```
a = [{'id':'1','name':'john'}, {'id':'2','name':'johns'}, {'id':'3','name':'rock'}
```

I want to display the dictionary of using the `id` value `'2'` to search the dictionary and the wanted output is like this

```
{'id':'2','name':'johns'}
```

How to display the dictionary to be like that?

Comment: It's not a dictionary. It's a list of dictionaries

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to write a linear search or a binary search for a sorted list?

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary like `{"1": "john", "2": "johns", "3": "rock"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, in O(n):

```
a = [{'id':'1','name':'john'}, {'id':'2','name':'johns'}, {'id':'3','name':'rock'}]

# [{'id': '2', 'name': 'johns'}]
print([d for d in a if d['id'] == '2'])
```

However representing data as dictionary is more efficient, in O(1):

```
a = {'1': {'name' : 'john'}, '2': {'name' : 'johns'}, '3': {'name' : 'rock'}}

# {'name': 'johns'}
print(a['2'])
```